# Im making a plex server on a raspberry pi, but i am unable to mount a network drive

Tags: networking, mount, samba, cifs, plex

I write the following command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=XXX,password=XXX //192.168.0.29/mp3/ /home/pi/DRIVE/share
```

and it returns with the following error:

> mount error(22): Invalid argument
>   Refer to mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

I'm all new to Linux, sorry if it's an easy mistake. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Sample syntax of what works for me . . . `sudo mount -t cifs //<IPAddress>/<ShareName> -o username=<username>,password=<password> /mnt/<ServerName>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pointing you to the man page (the manual) for mount.cifs, which is available [here](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) online or by typing `man mount.cifs` into terminal:

You have put your arguments in the wrong order. The manual indicated the order is...

```
mount.cifs {service} {mount-point} [-o options]
```

also, "username" is not the correct option for specifying username; it's "user".

so the correct mount command would be...

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.0.29/mp3/ /home/pi/DRIVE/share -o user=XXX,password=XXX
```